Does AMT Credit apply only to capital gains?
I'm getting very contradictory answers when it comes to when can I claim AMT credit. Is not clear whether the credit can be applied to any income/tax, or it has to be applied only to capital gains, or it has to be applied specifically to capital gains of the same ISO units for which the AMT was originally calculated.
Say in 2022 I payed 100k AMT on a ISO grant I purchased and hold. Which of the following is true?

In 2023 I did not sold any stock but I owe 50k tax on my salary.  I can claim AMT credit for it and don't pay anything.
In 2023 I sold other stock units and made capital gains. I can claim the the tax on that capital gain from my AMT credit.
In 2023 I sold some of the same units I purchased in 2022, long term hold. I can claim as AMT credit only the difference between ordinary income tax rate used when I payed my AMT and the long term tax that applies to my 2023 sale.
Something else?


Unfortunately the answer is 4: it's complicated. But 1-3 are likely true to an extent.
From 2022, you have an AMT carryforward credit. You use that credit every subsequent year when your regular income tax is larger than your AMT, to the extent of the difference, until it is used up. If you never owed AMT before 2022, it's very likely that going forward, your regular income tax will be higher than your AMT. By how much, which determines how much of the credit you can actually use per year, is hard to estimate. But you almost certainly won't be able to offset your entire tax bill at once unless you sell the stock received from exercising the ISOs.
Most likely, you will slowly chip away at the credit, a few hundred or a few thousand dollars a year, until you sell the ISO stock. The difference between AMT and regular income tax when you sell your stock is not due to the difference in rate, because both systems share the same long-term capital gains rate, but the difference in basis. In the regular tax system your basis is the exercise price, which is lower than the fair market value when you exercised, which is your basis in the AMT system. So in the year you sell, you should have a much larger capital gain in the regular tax system than the AMT system, which will allow you to claim all or most of the remaining credit.

Ty for the answer. It is indeed complicated :)
My main question is whether claiming the AMT credit is in any way related to selling the ISO on which it was based originally. Or claiming AMT has nothing to do with the ISO that caused it and is just related to my overall tax situation in 2023. Ie. can I claim AMT credit if I did not touch those ISO units?, and my regular income 2023 tax is lower than the AMT?

Credit is for AMT, not for ISOs.

@RemusRusanu You could potentially claim the entire AMT credit without touching the ISO stocks. But for most people it works out that they get the majority of the credit when selling the ISO stocks.

If I rememer I'll run a quick multi-year tax planning hypothetical and post a screenshot of it after I'm done with work. Craig's answer is correct, it's a mix of 1-3 (although less of 2 because long-term gains are generally taxed the same under the regular tax and AMT systems) and 4.
